# SQL Server Log Messages / Memory Clog

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddos

I have a dedicated server that's been running for years, with no recent code or configuration changes, but suddenly about a week ago, the MS SQL Server DB has started becoming unresponsive, and shortly thereafter, the entire site goes down due to memory issues on the server. It is sporadic, which leads me to believe it could be a malicious DDOS-like attack, but I am not sure how to confirm what's going on.

After a reboot, it can stay up for a few days, or only a few hours before I start seeing rampant occurrances of these Info messages in the Windows logs, shortly before it seizing up and failing. Research has not yielded any actionable info as of yet, please help, and thank you.

*Process 52:0:2 (0xaa0) Worker 0x07E340E8 appears to be non-yielding on Scheduler 0. Thread creation time: 13053491255443. Approx Thread CPU Used: kernel 280 ms, user 35895 ms. Process Utilization 0%%. System Idle 93%%. Interval: 6505497 ms.*

*New queries assigned to process on Node 0 have not been picked up by a worker thread in the last 2940 seconds. Blocking or long-running queries can contribute to this condition, and may degrade client response time. Use the "max worker threads" configuration option to increase number of allowable threads, or optimize current running queries. SQL Process Utilization: 0%%. System Idle: 91%%.*

Answer (score -1):

Here's a blog about the issue: [danieladeniji.wordpress](http://danieladeniji.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/microsoft-sqlserver-v2005-crashed-with-error-info-deadlocked-schedulers/) that should help you get started.

Seems unlikely that it would be a DDOS.